# Error declaring an Intent in from a Fragment in Kotlin:

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I am trying to create an intent that uses a button within a fragment in the main activity to open a new activity. The error pops up underlining the 'Intent' object with a red line. The error is:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
(Context!, Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
(String!, Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent

I tried the following code

```
val fieldIntent = Intent(this@Fragment1, ProductsAndInputs::class.java )
```

instead of the initial

```
val fieldIntent = Intent(this, ProductsAndInputs::class.java )
```

Based on an answer provided on a different forum but it also didn't work

```
    class Fragment1 : Fragment() {


        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false)

            view.btn_field.setOnClickListener { view ->
                val fieldIntent = Intent(this@Fragment1, ProductsAndInputs::class.java )
                Log.i("Button clicked", "Field button")
            }
            return view
        }
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that the Intent constructor wants a context, but you're passing it a Fragment. But you can get a context from the Fragment: try this:

```
 val fieldIntent = Intent(this@Fragment1.context, Products...
```

Oh, and you do need to call startActivity too, as Ajay said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code
val fieldIntent = Intent(this@Fragment1, ProductsAndInputs::class.java )
             startActivity(fieldIntent)